# Find out the root reference in sqlalchemy orm

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is a model has self-referential relationship, I want to find out the root node/record of the reference, for example in the following example, Package may depends on another package.

```
# myapp.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Package(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "packages"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    dep_on_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('packages.id'))
    dep_on = relationship('Package', remote_side=[id])

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Package (%r)>' % self.name
```

If package D depends on C, C depends on B, B depends on A, I want to find out the root depend package of D, which is A, So the expect result in the follwing test code should be `<Package (u'a')>`, is there an easy approach I can do with sqlalchemy to replace the `find_root_dep` function?

```
# test.py

from myapp import db, Package

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

a = Package('a')
b = Package('b')
c = Package('c')
d = Package('d')
b.dep_on = a
c.dep_on = b
d.dep_on = c

for p in [a, b, c, d]:
    db.session.add(p)
db.session.commit()

def find_root_dep(package):
    dep_on = package.dep_on
    while dep_on:
        dep = dep_on.dep_on
        if dep:
            dep_on = dep
        else:
            break
    return dep_on

print find_root_dep(d)
```

Comment: You could probably device a [recursive CTE](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to find the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walking trees and graphs can be done in SQL using a [recursive CTE](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html), or [`Query.cte()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte) in SQLAlchemy.

```
def find_root_dep(package):
    # The initial step. Find the 1st dependency of the Package passed
    # as the argument.
    cte = db.session.query(Package).\
        filter_by(id=package.dep_on_id).\
        cte(recursive=True)

    # The iterative step. Find Packages that found packages
    # depend on. Iteration stops when the query results in
    # an empty set, since no Package has NULL id.
    cte = cte.union_all(
        db.session.query(Package).
            filter_by(id=cte.c.dep_on_id))

    # Create an alias for returning an entity object.                
    result_alias = db.aliased(Package, cte)

    # The root depends on nothing.        
    return db.session.query(result_alias).\
        filter_by(dep_on_id=None).\
        one_or_none()
```

Your original implementation would return None, if passed a root package, so the SQL implementation starts directly by looking up the 1st dependency, which will result in an empty set for root packages.